# How to decode IEX DEEP pcap file

Tags: python, scapy, pcap

I am trying to decode DEEP data from IEX(the Investors Exchange), which is in pcap form. I am currently working in Python.

I am currently using Scapy to parse pcap file. The problem is that I do not know how to decode the raw load(binary form) into human-readable text. 
Here is an example.

```py
from scapy.all import *

packets = rdpcap(r'20171104_IEXTP1_DEEP1.0.pcap')
packets[0].show()
```

The result is like this

```
###[ Ethernet ]### 
  dst       = 01:00:5e:57:15:04
  src       = 00:1e:67:f2:62:24
  type      = 0x800
###[ IP ]### 
     version   = 4
     ihl       = 5
     tos       = 0x0
     len       = 68
     id        = 16005
     flags     = DF
     frag      = 0
     ttl       = 64
     proto     = udp
     chksum    = 0x49e2
     src       = 23.226.155.132
     dst       = 233.215.21.4
     \options   \
###[ UDP ]### 
        sport     = 10378
        dport     = 10378
        len       = 48
        chksum    = 0x6c15
###[ Raw ]### 
           load      = '\x01\x00\x04\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00BD\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xce/\xec:\x98\xde\xf3\x14'
```

Is there any way I can know the content of the raw load there? It is supposed to be information about the order book data. I do not see any existing tool to decode this.

If interested, you can access those files from the official website of IEX(https://iextrading.com/trading/market-data/#deep). Those pcap files are usually pretty large, so I am trying on a small one 20171104_IEXTP1_DEEP1.0.pcap.

Comment: Can you share sample PCAP file?

Comment: @Alderven Sure. I do not know how to attach files, so I edit the post to add the website to download those files. Hope it helps.

Comment: Have you read [specification](https://iextrading.com/docs/IEX%20TOPS%20Specification.pdf)?

Comment: @Alderven Yes, but I have no experience dealing with decoding problems. Even with specification, I have no clue how to get started.

Comment: You might need to implement the protocol in Scapy, so that you can access each field

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more readable dump of the load, try using the Scapy `hexdump` method:

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.utils import hexdump

packets = rdpcap(r'20180127_IEXTP1_DEEP1.0.pcap')
packets[0].show()

raw = packets[0].lastlayer()
hexdump(raw)
```

Which will output something like this:

```
###[ Ethernet ]### 
  dst       = 01:00:5e:57:15:04
  src       = 00:1e:67:f2:62:24
  type      = 0x800
###[ IP ]### 
     version   = 4
     ihl       = 5
     tos       = 0x0
     len       = 68
     id        = 53693
     flags     = DF
     frag      = 0
     ttl       = 64
     proto     = udp
     chksum    = 0xb6a9
     src       = 23.226.155.132
     dst       = 233.215.21.4
     \options   \
###[ UDP ]### 
        sport     = 10378
        dport     = 10378
        len       = 48
        chksum    = 0x955b
###[ Raw ]### 
           load      = '\x01\x00\x04\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x96D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x91\x08\xf0M:\xac\r\x15'

0000  01000480010000000000964400000000 ...........D....
0010  00000000000000000100000000000000 ................
0020  9108F04D3AAC0D15                 ...M:...
```